# PHP - Creating Nested Soap Headers using SoapClient

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I am using the `SoapClient` class in PHP to make a request. I am trying to create a nested header variable to pass in my request.

Currently my request headers looks like this,

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ns2:type>request</ns2:type>
    ...
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

I want it to look like this,

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ns2:ei>
        <ns2:type>request</ns2:type>
        ...
    </ns2:ei>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

I am currently creating the headers like this,

```
$headers[] = new SoapHeader(
        $nsp1,
        "type",
        "request"
    );
$headers[] = new SoapHeader(...)
```

I have tried various ways to nest the headers the including,

```
$headers[] = new SoapHeader(
   $nsp1,
   "ei",
   new SoapHeader(
        $nsp1,
        "type",
        "request"
    )
);
```

but this throws a fatal error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using an object or an array as the $data parameter

Object:

```
<?php
class MySoapHeader
{
    public $type = 123;
    public $value = 'UNKNOWN';
}

$headers1[] = new SoapHeader(
        'n1',
        'ei',
        new MySoapHeader()
    );

print_r ($headers1);
?>
```

Gives

```
Array ( [0] => SoapHeader Object ( [namespace] => n1 [name] => ei 
    [data] => MySoapHeader Object ( [type] => 123 [value] => UNKNOWN ) 
    [mustUnderstand] => ) )
```

Array:

```
<?php
    $headers2[] = new SoapHeader(
        'n1',
        'ei',
        array ('type'=>123,'value'=>'UNKNOWN')
    );

    print_r ($headers2);
?>
```

Gives

```
Array ( [0] => SoapHeader Object ( [namespace] => n1 [name] => ei
    [data] => Array ( [type] => 123 [value] => UNKNOWN ) [mustUnderstand]
    => ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't create nested instance, you can try something like these

```
//Untested
$strHeaderComponent_Ei = "<ei><type>$strType</type></ei>";

$objVar_Ei_Inside = new SoapVar($strHeaderComponent_Ei, XSD_ANYXML, null, null, null);
$objHeader_Ei_Outside = new SoapHeader($nsp1, 'ei', $objVar_Ei_Inside);
```

Comment: Using Re0sless approach seems to be working for me. I wanted to avoid writing out the XMLs. Thanks for another way to solve it though.